# Git Merge Issues After Merge Conflicts Resolved

Tags: git

I originally have main and branch A. Then I merged them. Then I modified something locally but saw 5k changes after I did "git add .". Then the origin remote disappeared (nothing returned after I did "git remote -v"). So I added a new remote origin with the same git remote url as deleted git("git add remote [git url]). But I only saw "master" branch. I did not name such a branch name. So I did "git pull --all". I then saw all branches pulled locally (main, branch A and master branch). Then the merge trouble began after I tried to merge master branch to main( "git merge origin master"). The error is as below. I checked every file and there's nothing I need to resolve. This whole thing caused failure of my Heroku deployment. I'm very anxious to get this fixed. Any hints and advice would be so appreciated!

> error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
> hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm '
> hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
> fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

Comment: This sounds like the terrible sorts of things that happen if you put a repository into a Dropbox folder or the like. (Don't do that!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I modified something locally but saw 5k changes after I did "git add .". Then the origin remote disappeared

Check first if you still have a `.git` subfolder in the right parent repository folder (and not in an ancestor folder, like $HOME or %USERPROFILE%, where *all* your files would be candidate to be tracked)

I would rather:

- rename with local cloned folder as 'tmprepo'
- clone again your remote repository
- report any modified files from tmprepo to your local cloned (again) repository
- add, commit and push